# UIViewController with Bar Button Item

Tags: xcode4, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, uibarbuttonitem

I'm using Xcode 4.4.1 with StoryBoard

- I have a UIViewController
- It is NOT embedded in a UINavigationController
- I drag in a UIBarButtonItem... not a ToolBar, just the bar button
- A ToolBar is created and placed on the bottom of the View in the UIViewController
- I now want to delete the UIBarButtonItem
- I delete the button, but the toolBar remains at the bottom of my view
- The ToolBar is not shown in the Document Outline

How do I get rid of this blank toolBar at the bottom of my UIViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your view controller.  In the Attributes Inspector, change the Bottom Bar setting from Toolbar to None.

[image: view controller bottom bar setting]

Comment: Missed the simulated metrics... Thanks!